# Чем можно заменить тире (расплодились)?

Tags: пунктуация, грамотная-речь, выбор-слов, тире

> Настоящая архитектура невероятна выразительна и передаёт нам очень
>   большое количество информации на визуальном уровне, на уровне кодов.
>   Она наиболее драматична – способна вызывать резкую смену поведения или
>   идей, она демократична – принадлежит всем – мне и каждому, кто заходит
>   или проходит мимо, архитектура – мать всем искусствам: росписи,
>   мозаика, скульптура – всё это лишь её комментарии, а ещё она
>   долговечнее из всех искусств, по крайней мере была так придумана, и
>   подтверждением тому – те самые здания, которые за две тысячи лет почти
>   не изменились…

"Долговечнее из всех" - можно? Выбросить "из"?

"...способна вызывать резкую смену поведения или идей" - или умонастроения?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Настоящая архитектура невероятно выразительна и передаёт нам очень
>   большое количество информации на визуальном уровне, на уровне кодов.
>   Она драматична – способна вызывать резкую смену поведения или идей;
>   она демократична, ибо принадлежит всем – мне и каждому, кто заходит в 
>   здание или проходит мимо; она мать всем искусствам: росписи, мозаика,
>   скульптура – всё это лишь её комментарии. А ещё она долговечнее всех
>   искусств, по крайней мере была так придумана. Подтверждение тому – те
>   самые здания, которые за две тысячи лет почти не изменились…

1. Убрал "наиболее" (не видно, с чем сравнение).
2. Три объединённых предложения (ввиду их распространённости) разделил точкой с запятой.
3. В третьем из этих предложений заменил "архитектуру" на "она" (повторяющееся местоимение здесь - формальное основание для объединения предложений в одно).
4. Во втором из объединённых предложений убрал первое тире введением союзного слова.
5. Следующие два предложения для разгрузки разделены. Первое из них самим автором (видимо, ощутившим перегруженность) обозначено (через "а ещё") как дополнение к предшествующей составной мысли.
6. Мелкие исправления окончаний.

Думаю, что "резкая смена поведения или идей" возможна, если автор в момент написания думал о спектакле, устроенном Гамлетом отчиму.

Comment: "Заходит ... мимо" — допустимо? "Её комментарии" — архитектура комментирует(?!)

Comment: "Она мать всем искусствам: росписи, мозаика, скульптура – всё это лишь её комментарии". Двоеточие путает, сбивает. Первое впечатление: "всем искусствам" — обобщающие слова; но потом оказывается, что это не так.

Comment: "Смена поведения или идей". Не люблю мух или котлеты. И почему ИЛИ, а не И? – М_Г 9 минут назад

Comment: Соответствие утверждений действительности - ответственность автора, я старался лишнего не трогать.

Comment: Я говорю о явных ошибках, я не об истинности суждений.

Comment: Насчёт "заходит" согласен; добавил "в здание" - оно важнее предлога, поскольку "зайти в архитектуру" не всегда можно. С и/или думаю, допустимы оба варианта (поведение может основываться и на безыдейных эмоциях).

Comment: Второе по важности — двоеточие. "Всем искусствам" — не обобщающие слова (падежи не соответствуют), так почему двоеточие?

Comment: После двоеточия здесь раскрывающее объяснение, почему "мать" (это не просто перечисление "детей").

Comment: Это объяснение, почему мать ВСЕМ?! Вы серьезно? Максимум (при том, что не знаю как тут толковать слово комментарии) это следствие из того, что она мать всем искусствам (а значит подходит тире, а не двоеточие). Но тире там не хочется ставить. Я поставил точку.

Answer (score 1):

Мой вариант:

**Настоящая архитектура невероятна выразительна и передаёт нам очень большое количество информации на визуальном уровне, на уровне кодов. Она наиболее драматична — способна вызывать резкую смену поведения или идей; она демократична — принадлежит всем: мне и каждому, кто заходит внутрь или проходит мимо. Архитектура – мать всем искусствам. Росписи, мозаика, скульптура – всё это лишь её элементы(*?*). А ещё она долговечнее всех искусств, по крайней мере была так придумана *(лучше — задумана)*, и подтверждением тому – те самые здания, которые за две тысячи лет почти не изменились…**

Пояснения.

> Встречается постановка двоеточия при пояснительном члене предложения. Обычно двоеточие ставится для того, чтобы избежать двух тире.
>
> Предложен и другой путь: использование некоторых видов морских растений – водорослей, богатых многими ценными веществами.

Корректно: "долговечнеее всех" или "самая долговечная из всех".

Про резкую смену. По-моему, архитектура и резкая смена — понятия плохо совместимые в приципе. И не могу принять, что архитектура наиболее драматична из всех искусств. Так что мучайтесь с этим без меня.

"Заходит или проходит мимо" - неверное сочетание (заходит мимо).

"Росписи, мозаика, скульптура – всё это лишь её комментарии"(?!). Если мать, то почему комментарии? Вообще, слово "комментарии" кажется мне неуместным в данном контексте. Возможно, "ее элементы" будет корректней.